# The output of the angular date filter shows 1 hour too much

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a very simple question. I'm just wondering why the amount of hours starts at 1 instead of 0 at my angular web app [RunnerCalc](http://runnercalc.tk/).

[image: It's in norwegian, so to explain: the number in front of the 't' is the amount of hours.]

The code for the output of duration is as follows:

```
<pre>Tid = {{(p.tempo*p.distanse)*60000 | date: "HH't' mm'min' ss'sek'"}}</pre>
```

In the Angular documentation for the Date filter it says that **HH** will start at **00** so I don't understand why it starts at **01**. I would be so happy if anyone could tell how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

That's because angular will use the timezone of the browser if you don't provide one in your date format. I don't think that angular's date filter should be used to format seconds, it's used to work with actual dates. You could create your own filter for this:

```
app.filter('formatSeconds', function() {
    return function(secs) {
        var d = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        d.setSeconds(secs);
        return d;
    };
});

{{(p.tempo*p.distanse)*60000 | formatSeconds | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Comment: I didn't get your suggested filter to work, but I found one online: https://github.com/erykpiast/angular-duration-format/blob/master/dist/angular-duration-format.js. Still, thanks for the help.